# convert vector of uint8_t to bitset

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, bitset, std

In the following code I've a `uint8_t` vector filled from some binary file which contains information in `some_size` number of bytes -

```
std::ifstream db(path.c_str(), std::ios::binary);
std::vector <uint8_t> buffer(some_size, 0);
db.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&buffer.front()), some_size);
db.close();
```

Now I know from some index say 20, there exists 37 bytes of either `1` or `0` which I need to fill into a `bitset`. The bitset looks like `std::bitset<37> booleans;` and is initialized to all `0`s initially. Now if initial index is 20, so I need to fill `booleans` with 37 boolean values that are present in bytes which will range from `buffer[20]` to `buffer[56]`.

Apart from looping over the vector and manually setting 1 or 0 on each bit in bitset, is there any other way to convert those bytes to this bitset?

Comment: I don't see how you're going to convert `uint8_t` to the type `bitset` uses without writing a loop or using a function that internally does the looping for you.  Either way, a loop is done.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie ofcourse a loop is required. But a manual loop vs using something like `std::copy` or `std::copy_n` is what I'm asking here.

Comment: The problem is that a `bitset` does not have iterators, thus algorithm functions such as `copy` or `copy_n` will be hard-pressed to do what you want.  The `for_each` is probably the best you can do, [something like this](http://ideone.com/KyPbvU).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie hmm that's what I thought. Care minding posting an answer, I'll accept that example as a valid one.

Comment: You loop or recurse. Either way iteration has to be done.

Comment: `reinterpret_cast<char *>(&buffer.front())`, Oo. Please replace by [`std::vector::data`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/data/)

Comment: @Stargateur what would be the difference?

Comment: @AbhinavGauniyal 1. this is not the purpose of [`std::vector::front`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/front/), 2. this is undefined behavior if the vector is empty, 3. use [`std::vector::data`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/data/) is the proper way to do this.

Comment: @Stargateur vector won't be empty, you'll have to resize the vector beforehand anyhow. Otherwise would the vector autoupdate it's size and other properties if I create it and directly write to `vector::data`?

Comment: @AbhinavGauniyal It's will be my last comment to avoid chat in the comment. "vector won't be empty" in your case, maybe, but it's not the point. I never say that [`std::vector::data`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/data/) must be used as an alias of the vector. It's a raw pointer only valid until you modify the vector. Your code is relatively unsafe you want use vector as an raw array. So use the proper method at least.

Comment: vector has been resized to `some_size` in it's constructor so `data` and `front` are exactly equal here.

Comment: @hg_git What is `some_size` equal `0`? You are wrong there method are **NOT** equal! There is a method to do that don't use the tricky unsafe method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you don't want to write a hand-coded loop, you can use `std::for_each`:

```
#include <bitset>
#include <cstdint>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::vector <uint8_t> buffer(100, 0);
    std::bitset<37> b;
    std::size_t i = 0;
    std::for_each(buffer.begin() + 20, buffer.begin() + 57, [&](uint8_t val)
    { b[i] = val; ++i; });
}
```

The underlying issue is that `std::bitset` doesn't have iterators, so the familiar STL algorithm functions such as `std::copy`, `std::copy_n`, `std::transform`, etc. that require iterators are difficult, if not impossible to be used if `std::bitset` is a source (or target) in the algorithm function.  Thus it seems that `std::for_each` with a lambda that increments an index will work.

Comment: Edited.  Also [this site](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset) is a better C++ documentation site.

Comment: you could put `i` in the capture list and make the lambda mutable, instead of declaring it outside of its scope, like so: `[&, i = std::size_t{0}] (uint8_t val) mutable ...`. It's a bit more verbose, but the intent becomes clearer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
std::vector<uint8_t> sourceVec{1,0,1,1,0};
std::stringstream strStream;
std::copy(sourceVec.begin(), sourceVec.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(strStream));
std::bitset<5> bitsetVar(strStream.str());
```

Comment: It's example only.